# PHP check IF non-empty, non-zero

Tags: php

I get the width and height of image with getimagesize function, like below:

```
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($source_pic);
```

How can I use IF condition to check that the getimagesize function executed without error and $width and $height got non-empty, non-zero values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($size = getimagesize($source_pic)) {
    list($width,$height) = $size;
    if($height > 0 && $width > 0) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this answer does not conform to all question requirements. In particular, it won't detect zero values.

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($width === NULL) {
    //handle error
}
```

If there's an error `getimagesize` returns `FALSE`, not an an array, so the `list` assignment will result in the variables being `NULL`.

Comment: You still need to test against zero. According to the manual, there are cases when you can get such value.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source_pic);
if( $width>0 && $height>0 ){
    // Valid image with known size
}
```

If it isn't a valid image, both $width and $height will be `NULL`. If it's a valid image but PHP could not determine its dimensions, they'll be `0`.

A note [from the manual](http://es.php.net/getimagesize):

> Some formats may contain no image or
>   may contain multiple images. In these
>   cases, getimagesize() might not be
>   able to properly determine the image
>   size. getimagesize() will return zero
>   for width and height in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
$size = getimagesize('image.jpg');
list($height,$width) = getimagesize('image.jpg');

if($height>0 && $width>0){
   //it comes into if block if and only if both are not null
}
```